# Dechunking a string in python

Tags: python

I have an array of bytes in python, which looks like this:

```
chunk_size = 8
a = b'12341234A12341234B12341234C12341234...'
```

I have to remove each nth byte (A, B, C in the example). Array length can be many thousands. Typical chunk size can be 128 or few thounds.

This is my current solution:

```
chunk_size = 8
output = b"".join([ i[:-1] for i in [ a[j:j+9] for j in range(0, len(a), chunk_size + 1) ]])
```

I am looking for other solutions, which could be more elegant.

Python 3.x only solutions are fine.

Comment: Can you add a desire output?

Comment: Added output variable to sample

Comment: Why you don't use `str.translate`? to replace uppercase letters with empty string.

Comment: @Kasra, OP wants to remove characters based on their position, not the characters themselves. Although valid for presented input, usage of `str.translate` seems to be less general than approach proposed by OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd pull the 'chunk and skip' logic out into a generator, something like:

```
>>> a = b'12341234A12341234B12341234C12341234'
>>> def chunkify(buf, length):
...    while len(buf) > length:
...       # get the next chunk from the buffer
...       retval = buf[:length]
...       # ...and move along to the next interesting point in the buffer.
...       buf = buf[length+1:]
...       yield retval
...
>>> for chunk in chunkify(a, 8):
...    print chunk
...
12341234
12341234
12341234
>>> ''.join(chunk for chunk in chunkify(a, 8))
'123412341234123412341234'
```

Comment: Chunkify. This tickles me.

Comment: Cool solution. Although it may be better to introduce position index instead of recreating `buf` over and over again.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, especially if the buffers get large, but I'd wait to see an issue before making that change, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Something as simple as the following should do:

```
chunk_size = 8
a = b'12341234A12341234B12341234C12341234...'
b"".join(a[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(a), chunk_size+1))
```

This works, because we process `chuck_size+1` bytes in every iteration, but only keep `chunk_size` of them, effectively removing a byte after every chunk.

Answer (score 3):

Convert to a `bytearray`, and then delete the unwanted elements:

```
>>> chunk_size = 8
>>> a = b'12341234A12341234B12341234C12341234'
>>> b = bytearray(a)
>>> del b[chunk_size::chunk_size + 1]
>>> b
bytearray(b'12341234123412341234123412341234')
```